# Instagram - jQuery - Authentication

Tags: jquery, api, instagram

The twitter API allows me to get a list of my tweets, or anyone elses via search without the need to authenticate. Is this possible with Instagram? I would like to get my own photos without having to log in. Has anyone been able to make an `$.ajax()` call to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You must register your server or program with Instagram and get a `CLIENT-ID`. You can then call the Instagram API with that client id, though you will get more detail if you use access tokens as an authenticated user.

Quick example to get the most popular photos at the moment (Replace `{CLIENT-ID}` with your own ID):

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  cache: false,
  url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id={CLIENT-ID}",
  success: function(response) {
    for (var i=0; i<25; i++)  
    {
       $("#photos").append("<div class='instagram-pics'><a target='_blank' href='" + response.data[i].link +"'><img class='instagram-img' src='" + response.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"' /></a></div>");  
    }
  }
});
</script>
<div id="photos"></div>
```